# Mark method as should never be used

Tags: java, reactivex

i would like to know if there is some good way in java to show that some method should never be invoked? I'm thinking in case that I work with bigger team, and to tell guys that this method will never be invoked, so don't try to test it. Maybe assert is a good idea?

Context: i'm using ReactiveX in java and my Observable will never be stopped, it can only invoke onError and onNext, but onCompleted will never be invoked, but my Observer extends Subscriber so i need to @Override onCompleted.

Comment: @Deprecated annotation.

Comment: Can you not just either remove the method or throw an UnsupportedOperationException?

Comment: But @Deprecated should be used with old method which are only for backward compatibility i think. That is why i'm asking about good way to tell that this method will not be invoked in program ever, not it shouldn't be invoked

Comment: @BretC i need to implement this because I extend Observer class. UnsupportedOperationException seems reasonable to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Deprecated` is the closest standard thing, and throwing `UnsupportedOperationException` is a reasonable thing to do in many similar cases.

Note also that due to polymorphism, the caller may well not know the concrete type of the `Observer` they are calling until runtime, so no annotation could help.

However, in the case you've described, I think you should write an empty implementation of `onCompleted()` and a test that just asserts that it doesn't throw an exception. Although you've decided that the Observable will never stop producing, it doesn't seem reasonable to throw an exception if one day it does.

Comment: I think that better test is to test it should throw an exception, to make sure that contract with my Observable never stopping producing elements is preserved. If someone will change it then test will won't go, and we will know that someone tried to break contract.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want others to invoke the method then make use `@Deprecated` annotation with proper java doc.
Note that, its just an indication to the caller, though they can still call the method.

Comment: As I wrote in comment below my question i don't like idea of using Deprecated in such situation